# Rails: if statement in .map()

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I want to map some values from a table to an array. Works fine, except for the fact that the database has some `nil` values in it, which creates invalid JSON. So far I have this:

```
@markers = ExtendedProfile.all.map{|u|[u.city, u.latitude, u.longitude]}
```

Now what I want to do is check if the fields are filled in, and if not, enter a default value. So for example `if u.latitude == nil` I want to enter `0.0` in the array, instead of `nil`. Any idea about how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `u.latitude || 0.0`:

```
@markers = ExtendedProfile.all.map{|u|[u.city, u.latitude || 0.0, u.longitude || 0.0]}
```

Answer (score 2):

For better understanding, you can extend to the `map` block syntax like this:

```
@markers = ExtendedProfile.all.map do |u|
  if u.latitude.nil?
    [0, 0]
  else
    [u.city, u.latitude, u.longitude]
  end
end
```

Comment: Good to know you can extend to block syntax! I accepted Graeme's answer because it better suited the problem I had right now, but this will definitely be helpful in the future, thanks!